# Cambiar de color un DIV al presionar un checkbox (Problema con botón Seleccionar Todos)

Tags: javascript

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer esta consulta, paso a comentar, logré implementar el cambio de color del div cuando el checkbox es presionado, pero independientemente de esto agregué un botón para seleccionar todos los checkboxes a la vez, el conflicto es que si uso el botón los DIV no cambian de color, en cambio al presionar uno por uno, es decir manualmente si funciona. Cómo podré triggerear que al utilizar el botón SELECCIONAR TODOS también cambien de color? Les muestro el javascript que estoy utilizando para esto.

```
//check todos
var clicked = false;
$(".checkall").on("click", function() {
  $(".print").prop("checked", !clicked);
  clicked = !clicked;
  this.innerHTML = clicked ? 'Quitar seleccion' : 'Selecionar Todo';
});
//cambiar color if checked
$('.print').on('change', function() {
  var div = $(this).closest('.panel-featured-primary');
  $(this).is(":checked") ? div.addClass("checkeado") : div.removeClass("checkeado");
});
```

Css Utilizado:

```
.checkeado {
    border-color: #d51f1f !important;
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Ahí agregué el CSS utilizado

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un trozo del HTML también?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No nos has pasado el html.

Pero en principio

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").trigger('click');
```

Hacer esto luego de setear el attr `checked` debiera funcionar

Recuerda leer la documentacion https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, son detalles que se nos escapan a los que recién comenzamos. Muchas gracias!!